# A very simple question about an integration problem

Tags: calculus, area

I have recently returned to school and am currently brushing up on some old Calculus before the next semester begins. I'm working several problems from the MIT Calculus book online and have come across this one :

**9) Draw $y = \sin x$ from $0$ to $\pi$. Three rectangles (base $\dfrac{\pi}{3}$)
and six rectangles (base $\dfrac{\pi}{6}$) contain an arch of the sine function. Find the areas and guess the limit.**

My problem is that I can't figure out why there is a discrepancy between my answer and the one provided in the solutions manual.

The solutions manual states that the solution is $\dfrac{\pi}{3} ( 1 + {\sqrt 3})$ ,  $\dfrac{\pi}{6} (3 + {\sqrt 3})$ , $2$.

Now. I'm not really interested in getting the whole answer, I will show you what I did, and I would like somebody to show me why I am looking at this wrong.

We can just stick to the first part, because after that I can try it from there.

I tried to paste a picture, but the picture taken from my phone was too large a file size.

So, I will just say I drew the sin curve from $0$ to $\pi$ : It increases, reaches a maximum at $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ , and then unfolds its way symmetrically back down to $\pi$ , as sin curves are won't to do.

I moved over to $\dfrac{\pi}{3}$ drew a vertical line to $\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{3}\right) = \dfrac{\sqrt3}{2}$ and  drew leftward back $\dfrac{\pi}{3}$ and down for the first rectangle. I repeated that again starting at $\dfrac{\pi}{3}$  and then on the third one $\sin(\pi)=0$ , so I ended up with two rectangles (not three, perhaps this is the start of my difficulty) .

The area of this is equal to $\dfrac{\pi}{3}\left( \dfrac{\sqrt3}{2}  + \dfrac{\sqrt3}{2}\right) = \dfrac{\pi}{3}(\sqrt 3)$ .

Therefore , I am off by one extra $\dfrac{\pi}{3}$. I want to know where this extra $\dfrac{\pi}{3}$ is coming from.

No point in going through the rest of the problem as the process is the same and I get a wrong answer there as well.

Thank you very much for any help you have to offer.

Comment: It sounds like maybe they want you to compute upper sums, with 3 and with 6 equal-width intervals.  These were chosen because sine can be evaluated exactly on the points required.

Answer (score 1):

It is advantageous to use a symbol at first and the assign a value later for limits defining the desired interval. Vary $i$ from 1 to 6 in the area integral of each one-sixth slice:

$$ \int_{(i-1) \pi/6}^{i \pi/6} \sin x dx $$